# Python multiprocessing based WSGI webserver

Tags: python, multiprocessing, wsgi, cpython

I am currently hosting REST webservice based on Bottle/Paste combination. However the application starts choking when there are about 50 concurrent threads.

Paste uses multi-threading and hence limited by the GIL.

I am planning to use CherryPy-WSGI server. My question is, does it use multi-threading or does it use multi-processing ? 
Also can I use it with Bottle ?

Environment :

- CPython 2.7
- Bottle + Paste
- Win server 2003, 4 core CPU

Comment: Is your server WinXp?

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down. None of the architecture pages of cherryPy or other wsgi servers answer this very basic question.

Guido himself recommends multiprocessing instead of multithreading, and then at all the documentation of various servers don't clearly state this. 
I think it should be a key question that everybody should ask about python based servers.

Comment: @Bhushan The home page of CherryPy says "A fast, HTTP/1.1-compliant, WSGI thread-pooled webserver."

Comment: Actually it was more of a question around multi-processing vs multi-threading. 
I don't understand why the webservers should use multi-threading instead of processing. That's why the initial question was in search of a webserver which is multi-processing based..

Comment: You can run bottle with (server="gunicorn", workers=64) to have multi-processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/). It is not multiprocessing, but it's asynchronous and well scalable, and it can support a good number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: I suppose I don't have to code my business logic differently.

Comment: Your business logic won't be affected (as long as it doesn't involve handling concurrency -multithreading in your case- explicitly.), its the handling of requests and response that will change to the most extend.

Comment: If you didn't program specifically for async, it wouldn't make sense running the code with async server.